# mysql join multiple tables and sum data

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables products ,sale_details , purchase_details the [sale_details] and [purchase_details] have [quantity] and [product_id].

I want a query to return something like this :

Product_id | SUM_SALE_DETAILS | SUM_PURCHASE_DETAILS

I construct a code below but its returning the wrong sum

```
SELECT products.code AS pcode,products.name AS pname,sale_details.product_id,sale_return_details.product_id,purchase_details.product_id,
SUM(sale_details.quantity) AS Total_Sales ,
SUM(purchase_details.quantity) AS Total_Purchase,
SUM(sale_return_details.quantity) AS Total_Sale_Return
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN sale_details 
ON products.id = sale_details.product_id 
LEFT JOIN purchase_details 
ON products.id = purchase_details.product_id 
LEFT JOIN sale_return_details 
ON products.id = sale_return_details.product_id 
GROUP BY pname
ORDER BY Total_Sale_Return DESC
```

Comment: No, you must SUM by separate table in the subquery then join. in current state you see "join multiplying" - each value is added many times according to matched rows amount in joined table.

Comment: @Akina hi, I would appreciate if you give examples for me to get to right path. thank you

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM (SELECT SUM(x) FROM y GROUP BY z) t JOIN (SELECT SUM(x1) FROM y1 GROUP BY z1) t1 ..```